# c programming, disable user input into terminal

Tags: c

Hi is there any possible way to temporarily disable user input into the terminal in c programming language?

There is probably a very good reason why you can't (possible malicious uses) but if its possible, can someone please illustrate how? maybe there is a function, a setting or even an obscure system command?

For context: a friend was having issues with a hard drive, so i created a program which ran a few terminal command and printed the output to a text file which he would send me. It all worked fine, however he didn't really know what he was doing so i printed instructions to the console to instruct him in what to do. although this all worked out, the thought did occur that i could potentially disable user input for that particular terminal window until it was required, and thus the question.

Its also a pretty basic question so if its actually a duplicate (although i could not find one) than please label as such.

Comment: The answer to that question is platform specific. I think in the general case a portable program knows little about the environment its running in. It could, for example, not be connected to any console at all and talk to pipes.

Comment: What OS is this? How did you write the instructions? From the program itself?

Comment: Yeah its Mac OS X, i printed the instructions directly from the program. What im asking isn't crucial to the programs execution, it would just make  life a lot simpler for the recipient of the program if they could only input to the terminal when the program allows you too, because you can still type into the terminal when its fulfilling other tasks and not reading input, and that may confuse someone who doesn't know terminal.